# How to populate dynamic textbox with selected data from a List Component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Currently I have a list component which is automatically populated with data from a mySQL database. Code for this is shown below.

Is it possible to select a variable from the list and store it as a seperate variable? Thus enabling me to display it back to the user when required.

```
var theXML:XML = new XML();
theXML.ignoreWhite = true;

theXML.onLoad = function() {
    var nodes = this.firstChild.childNodes;
    for(i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
        theList.addItem(nodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue,i);
    }
}

theXML.load("http://localhost/fyptest/products.php");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access the list data with `getItemAt(n)` where n is the index of the row you want.
You can get more details and a example [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002548.html).

For example in your case `var myLabel = theList.getItemAt(0)` will return the first item value.